# Can't get google-maps-directions Polymer element to work

Tags: google-maps, polymer

I've been trying to use the `google-map-directions` element in my app. Here is the code:

```
<google-map map="{{map}}" latitude="37.779" 
  longitude="-122.3892" zoom="13" disable-default-ui>
</google-map>

<google-map-directions map="{{map}}" 
  start-address="San Francisco"
  end-address="Mountain View"></google-map-directions>
```

I am getting this error in the console:

`Uncaught TypeError: window.google.maps.Load is not a function`

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you including both the `google-map` and the `google-map-directions` imports? Where is this code in your app? Is it in an `index.html` file or another element?

Comment: I wrote the answer in the other site, because the code is too long and dont have space here

Comment: this code works, the problem i did have is the version of google-maps-direcctions, I downloaded the branch of your gitHub and work it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I include both, here is the element complete:

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../google-map/google-map.html">
<link rel="import" href="../google-map/google-map-directions.html">

<dom-module id="mapa-direccion" >
<style>
   google-map {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}
</style>
<template is="dom-bind">
    <google-map id='s' map="{{map}}" latitude="37.779" longitude="-122.3892"></google-map>
        <google-map-directions map="{{map}}"
            startaddress="San Francisco"
            endaddress="Mountain View"
            travel-mode="TRANSIT">
    </google-map-directions>
</template>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "mapa-direccion",
    });
</script>
</dom-module>
```